# PHPExcel_Shared_Date::ExcelToPHP($val) returns default date if $val is invalid date

Tags: php, excel, date

I have this

```
new DateTime(date($format = "Y-m-d", PHPExcel_Shared_Date::ExcelToPHP($val))).
```

Everything works fine if the date is a valid date (like `1/1/2017`), but if I put a date like `'30/2/2000'` in Excel, the function from above returns `'1900-01-30 00:00:00.000000'.`
Is there a way to tell that function not to convert if it is not a valid date?

For ex,  `new DateTime` returns `FALSE` if the value is not a valid date, but `ExcelToPHP` always returns `a date` and I don't need that.

=== EDIT ===

Apparently if the Excel cell is formatted as Date, the value I receive in PHP is a number: the number of days that passed from `01-01-1900`.  For an invalid date, it will return the value as a string, not a number.

I think 2 things can work here:

1. check if it is a number or a string
2. convert to a readable PHP format and validate that result

I choose the second one:

```
$stringDate = \PHPExcel_Style_NumberFormat::toFormattedString($val, 'DD-MM-YYYY');

if (strtotime($stringDate) === false) {
  // throw error or do something if is not a valid date
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check date using `strtotime()` method then add conversation accoording to condition

```
if(strtotime($val) === false)
{
  //INVALID DATE
}
else
{
  new DateTime(date($format = "Y-m-d", PHPExcel_Shared_Date::ExcelToPHP($val)));  
}
```

Comment: In Excel I have 1/1/1980, in PHP I receive 29221. So strtotime will be false even if I have a valid date.

Comment: No @taysia09 strtotime return time stamp for `1/1/1980`. result is : `315532800`

Comment: I just tried. $val = 29221, so it will be strtotime(29221) ==> false

Comment: If in excel there is `1/1/1980` then why you receive `29221` in PHP?

Comment: Because in Excel is formatted as Date, not General and I guess it is calculated as the number of days since a certain date. 
I cannot change the Excel file, so I have to work with that.

Comment: I found a solution for this. Edited my question. Thanks @B. Desai